# How does CurveZMQ security work?

Tags: security, authentication, zeromq

From [their documentation](http://curvezmq.org/page:read-the-docs:):

> Clients and servers have long-term permanent keys, and for each
>   connection, they create and securely exchange short-term transient
>   keys. Each key is a public/secret keypair, following the elliptic
>   curve security model.
>
> To start a secure connection the client needs the server permanent
>   public key. It then generates a transient key pair and sends a HELLO
>   command to the server that contains its short term public key. The
>   HELLO command is worthless to an attacker; it doesn't identify the
>   client.
>
> The server, when it gets a HELLO, generates its own short term key
>   pair (one connection uses four keys in total), and encodes this new
>   private key in a "cookie", **which it sends back to the client** as a
>   WELCOME command. It also sends its short term public key, encrypted so
>   only the client can read it. It then discards this short term key
>   pair.
>
> At this stage, the server hasn't stored any state for the client. It's
>   generated a keypair, sent that back to the client in a way only the
>   client can read, and thrown it away.
>
> The client comes back with an INITIATE command that provides the
>   server with its cookie back, and the client permanent public key,
>   **encrypted as a "vouch" so only the server can read it**. As far as the
>   client is concerned, the server is now authenticated, so it can also
>   send back metadata in the command.
>
> The server reads the INITIATE and can now authenticate the client
>   permanent public key. It also unpacks the cookie and gets its short
>   term key pair for the connection. As far as the server is now
>   concerned, the client is now authenticated, so the server can send its
>   metadata safely. Both sides can then send messages and commands.
>
> This handshake provides a number of protections but mainly, perfect
>   forward security (you cannot crack data encrypted using the short term
>   keys even if you record it, and then later get access to the permanent
>   keys) and protection of client identity (the client permanent public
>   key is not sent in clear-text).

I can understand that they are basically generating new set of key-pairs for each communication session, so that cracking and obtaining temporary private keys for one session, or obtaining permanent private keys, will still protect recorded past communication that was done through a different set of private keys.

What I don't get is the cookie part. What purpose does the cookie serve exactly? Why should the server pass the cookie to client, only to get it back again? It doesn't look like the client uses the cookie anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess zeromq uses TCP SYN cookies (may be transaction cookies not sure).
This is to protect the server from DDOS attacks.

When TCP packets are sent with a first sequence number 'n' (with some complex mathematical functions). The receiver then needs to acknowledge this with 'n+1' sequence. The sender then subtracts 1 and gets the initial sequence number ('n').

The SYN cookies are placed in this initial sequence so that if at all there is a DDOS flood, the sequence will be tampered and the server cannot retrieve the cookie. Then it cannot complete the handshake process and thus terminates the connection.

In any legitimate handshake, the cookie cannot be tampered. So the Curve Server discards this immediately after sending to client to verify the authenticity of the client.

More info:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_cookies

There are two main purposes in this handshake process:

1. Do not store anything related to the client (or its state) till it is authenticated. Hence the short-term key pair is discarded (Remember, Each connection with client has a separate keypair - transient)
2. Authentication from both ends

   a. First client gets the cookie and servers transient keypair encrypted with clients transient public key. Now from clients perspective server is authenticated, since it sent the data in client understandable encryption.

   b. Second when the client sends back the cookie (server transient keypair), encrypted using server longterm public key, server decrypts, validates the cookie and gets the client permanent public key.Now the client is authenticated

Answer (score 0):

I went into the same questions. I found my answer in the [HELLO Command](http://curvezmq.org/page:read-the-docs#toc9) section of [the documentation](http://curvezmq.org/page:read-the-docs).

> When the server gets a valid HELLO command, it SHALL generate a new
>   transient key pair, and encode both the public and secret key in a
>   WELCOME command, as explained below. *The server SHALL not keep this
>   transient key pair and SHOULD keep minimal state for the client* until
>   the client responds with a valid INITIATE command. **This protects
>   against denial-of-service attacks where unauthenticated clients send
>   many HELLO commands to consume server resources.**